# Regarding API rate limit. Is is for a single app or a single user?

Tags: coinbase-api

In Coinbase API doc, it describes

"By default, **each API key or app is rate limited at 10,000 requests per hour** if your requests are being rate limited. HTTP response code 429 will be returned with an rate_limit_exceeded error"

[Question] I'd like to know that whether the current API restrictions are for a single app or a single user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, the limit is linked to the API key.

So if you have multiple apps using the same API key(ideally you should not), the limit will apply to the cumulative calls from all the apps. If you have separate apps using different keys, the limit will apply to each app.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Anupam's answer, if you use the exchange api there are different rates and limited by IP.

> **REST API**
>
> When a rate limit is exceeded, a status of 429 Too Many Requests will be returned.
>
> **Public endpoints**
>
> We throttle public endpoints by IP: 10 requests per second, up to 15 requests per second in bursts. Some endpoints may have custom rate limits.
>
> **Private endpoints**
>
> We throttle private endpoints by profile ID: 15 requests per second, up to 30 requests per second in bursts. Some endpoints may have custom rate limits.
>
> /fills endpoint has a custom rate limit of 10 requests per second, up to 20 requests per second in bursts.

Comment: what are bursts exactly ? How do we know that we are "in bursts"